# Error in Specifying Layout in Joomla component

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have been working with the development of a component. Now I have a form in the component

that is submitting to a index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=myTask. Now in the controller

I have the function myTask() and I am specifying the view and layout like this

```
    $model = $this->getModel('mymodel');

    $view =& $this->getView('myview');

    $view->setModel($model, true );

    $view->displayReports();
```

I have the displayReports() function in the view.html.php and it is like this

```
function displayReports($tpl = null){

    global $mainframe;

    $this->_layout = 'viewcjreport';

    $reports= & $this->get('Reports');

    $this->assignRef('reports',$reports);

    parent::display($tpl);

}
```

But when I submit the form I am getting error as 'View not found [name, type, prefix]: 
cjunction,,kingdomView'.

Please let me know what is the issue here and how can I specify the 
view correctly. It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory to make this work you need to create

```
class kingdomView_cjunction extends JView{
}
```

in components/views/cjunction/view.html.php